# correct way of handling rvm, bundle, git, and branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rvm, bundle

So I am working on a RoR project.
I needed to fork the repo and am working on fixing issues on my own fork, issuing pull requests for the non-trivial changes. The main repo owner requests to create branches for issue fixes.

What is a correct way of handling this with rvm, bundle and git branches?

My problems may be related in not fully understanding RoR/rvm, gems and bundle. Do I need to run `bundle install` for every new branch I create? I have had problems in that `bundle install` worked after some fiddling with the Gemfile in the master branch (there was a mistake here in the owner's master repo), but then failed again in new branches.

Comment: I know this questions is a bit old. But I've finally gotten around to jot down the steps I use, to deal with different RVM gemsets for git branches. Maybe it could help those who stumbles on this. http://is.gd/pao3ZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you should only need to run `bundle install` when you add new gems to the Gemfile.

RVM should not come into this at all, unless you're testing on multiple versions of Ruby simultaneously.

In regard to branches, what I usually do is, having forked the repository, creating branches for large features. Once done, I issue a pull request for that branch, and once accepted I merge that into my local fork, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

RVM - Ruby Version Manager. This should not really come into play, you may need to change versions ONCE or TWICE to fix an issue, but you will pretty much always be on the newest ruby version.

bundle - Use bundle as a tool to update gems + dependencies. Pro tip - you can just run `bundle` instead of `bundle install`. You should also read about the different groupings such as

```
group :assets do
 gem 'sass' # or whatever
end
```

and then you have you `:development` group (gems you only use in development). and `:production` (opposite of development).

GIT - This is the heart and soul of your project. The popular workflow is to branch off

`git checkout -b mybranch`

Then you are in kind of a "safe zone" where you are free to play around. You make some important changes, you commit, and add the files you added if necessary.

`git add -A`

`git commit -am "commit message"`

and then when you are done you can merge the new branch back into your master branch

`git checkout master`
`git merge mybranch`

PRO TIP: Before you leave work on friday, commit your changes before going out. If you try and work hungover theres a good chance you'll do more damage than good, and you'll want to reset.

`git reset --hard`

Good luck!

Happy coding!

-Brian